# DataContractSerializer WriteObject as Stream does not use DataContractResolver set in Constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, datacontractserializer

I am serializing and deserializing class objects which might or might not be marked with known types.  Therefore, I have created my own DataContractResolver to handle loading knowntypes found in the referenced assembly.  I have been stumped on why WriteObject(stream, object) does not use the DataResolver set in the DataContractSerialization constructor.  When looking at the DataContractSerialization WriteObject method, it appears to instantiate an XmlDictionaryWriter for you:

```
public virtual void WriteObject(Stream stream, object graph)
{
    XmlObjectSerializer.CheckNull(stream, "stream");
    XmlDictionaryWriter xmlDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false);
    this.WriteObject(xmlDictionaryWriter, graph);
    xmlDictionaryWriter.Flush();
}
```

But then it appears to set the Resovler to null instead of checking for a Resolver.

```
internal void WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, object graph)
{
    this.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(writer, graph, null);
}
```

My question to the group is whether this appears to be a bug or is by design.  If by design, any thoughts on best way to use a derived DataResolver?  It seems confusing you can set the Resolver in the construct but it is not always used.

I mocked up a quick sample to show how I am using it in my code. Unfortunately, I cannot submit my code for public review.  Thank you for your help.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DummyClass dummyclass = new DummyClass { MyString = "MyString", One = 1 };
        DataContractSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings { DataContractResolver = new MyResolver() };

        string serializedobject = String.Empty;

        using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memorystream))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(dummyclass.GetType(), settings);

            //This does not call the Resolver set in the constructor
            serializer.WriteObject(memorystream, dummyclass);
            memorystream.Position = 0;
            serializedobject = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(serializedobject);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyResolver : DataContractResolver
{
    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null) ?? Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + typeNamespace);
    }

    public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString typeName, out System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        //This does not get called
        return knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
    }
}

public class DummyClass
{
    public int One { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It appears settings is not called when you pass a stream to WriteObject.  Also, the other reason the code above would not use a DataContractResolver is because the Serialized type is the same.  In other words, when instantiating a DataContractSerializer, you should pass in the base class if you are trying to serialized derived class types.